# How to synchronize data in different disk folders

Tags: backup

In my Ubuntu machine I have one big external disk, which is used to backup some data for my machine. Suppose the data I want to backup is in this location `/home/user_name/workspace/data`, and the data kept in this folder will be copied to my big external disk `/media/external_disk/backup/data`. As the data kept in the backup folder will increase after some time, I have to copy it to the external disk regularly. I was wondering whether there are some tools or scripts that can help me.

For the data kept in my local machine, they will not change but increase. For example, in the beginning there may be one files in the folder:

```
/home/user_name/workspace/data
                          ----file1.txt
```

After several days, it will change to:

```
 /home/user_name/workspace/data
                              ----file1.txt
                              ----file2.txt
                              ----new_folder
                                  ---------file3.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[rsync](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/rsync.1.html) is the classic tool for this purpose, although here are many others. The simplest command is `rsync -av "/path/to/source" "/path/to/destination"`